# Getting appended items to detect when hovering links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

In one of my projects, I am replacing the default cursor in the browser with an SVG one. I am appending this SVG cursor via jQuery. This works fine, but I want to change the cursor when it hovers over links, and right now, nothing I have tried has worked.

I think it is because even though the cursor has a position of fixed and a high z-index value, it cannot tell what it is hovering over because technically it is below the content.

Does anyone have suggestions?

EDIT: Right after I posted this question and after I included a JS Fiddle in the comments, I changed my code to make the cursor appear before the content. The issue remains, however.

Comment: Are you sure the SVG is on top in the DOM?

Comment: First of all, why the hell did I get downvoted? Secondly, I experience the same issue regardless of if the SVG is appended or prepended.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your HTML and JS?

Comment: Sure @A1rPun: http://jsfiddle.net/65yWk

Comment: I'm using Chrome and the svg cursor is on top of the text and link.

Comment: Yeah, but hovering over the link doesn't add the class I want to add. It doesn't do anything. I'm using the latest Opera, so I'm technically on Chrome too.

Comment: The hover event doesn't appear to be firing. A quick google search didn't give any obvious clues to why that's the case but here's a simple version using mouseover/mouseout that does what you're asking: http://jsfiddle.net/qjA55/

Comment: Sweet, that works well @mcbex! Thanks for your help. Do you want to put your answer in the answer section so you can get karma?

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby I'm glad it works! No worries about the karma, I couldn't really say why your version wasn't working anyway so just happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look above in the comments for @mcbex's JS Fiddle! Apparently, one does not simply add a class to an SVG, one must customize it with fill colors.